# all.js:23 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I get this error
**all.js:23 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =**

For this code. It worked hours ago... Maybe a temporary bug by facebook

```
<script>
  console.info("Init Facebook...")
  window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
      FB.init({
          appId:'1234567890'
          status:true, // check login status
          cookie:true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml:true  // parse XFBML
      });

      console.info("Facebook SDK running!")
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
  }(document));
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Switched to de_DE for the moment. Everything is working for now.

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js";
```

Comment: Any idea what causes this? I'm now experiencing this issue like 4 months after it is posted...and it worked before.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want js SDK to render language other than English then you can call the British locale like

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js";
```

It will solve your loading issue of en_US locale and also will keep the English language.

Comment: Any idea what causes this? I'm now experiencing this issue like 4 months after it is posted...and it worked before.

Comment: Thats a clever solution. Worked like a charm (y)

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. It looks like it's a problem on Facebook's end. There was a weird definition in the downloaded files on their servers... the 'en_GB' patch worked for me as well, but it's not a good solution (I use 'all' to be international)... I tried again half an hour later and things are now back in working order...

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a comma after appId:'1234567890'